# Content-Length header is not set in Golang http client request using PUT method

Tags: http, go, put, content-length

I'm using Golang 1.4.2 (built from source) and when I try to make an HTTP PUT request via http.Client.Do() the Content-Length header is missing from the request. All my other headers are sent... Am I doing something wrong? When I make the same request via CURL the content-length header is sent. My requests are being made to etcd server, which is setting all my keys to empty values. While this is somewhat novel, it is hardly useful. :)

http://play.golang.org/p/pIoB--bXUT

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    put := url.Values{}
    put.Set("value", "WHOAH here is my stuff")
    put.Add("ttl","")
    encode := put.Encode()
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("PUT", "http://localhost:2379/v2/keys/somekey", bytes.NewBufferString(encode))
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(encode)))
    req.Header.Add("X-Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(encode)))
    dump, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
    fmt.Println(string(dump))
}
```

yields

```
PUT /v2/keys/somekey HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Content-Length: 33

ttl=&value=WHOAH+here+is+my+stuff
```

Comment: ehrm... the request you dumped seems to have a `Content-Type` header set.

Comment: Code is working. Not a question.

Comment: Given the rest of the question, I suspect he meant the `Content-Length` header: that's the one not included in the output.

Comment: If it's content-length that's missing, then you need DumpRequestOut, since that header isn't one you can override, and is set by the Transport.

Comment: @JimB DumpRequestOut was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Or you can use `req.ContentLength = len(encode)` to set the length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was incorrect about Content-Length not being sent, I just wasn't seeing it when using httputil.DumpRequest.

Solution here was to use httputil.DumpRequestOut which properly shows the Content-Length header (and others). It means there is something else going on with my program that is causing etcd to set empty values. If I figure that out I'll update with that solution as well.

Comment: The overall problem had nothing to do with the HTTP request but instead were the json tags I was using for the etcd response. I was storing json in an etcd key/value, and passing that into json.RawMessage type, which I assumed would be better for subsequent json.Unmarshal calls on that data. The issue, however, is that the json.RawMessage []bytes was being quoted, so I needed to unquote before unmarshaling. I decided to just use a string type on this instead and convert to []byte when passing into json.Unmarshal.

Answer (score 4):

If you are saying header `Content-Length` is not set (actually it is set automatically just not showed up when dumping it), it works as designed because the following headers are excluded in `httputil.DumpRequest()` even you set them explicitly:

- `Host`
- `Content-Length`
- `Transfer-Encoding`
- `Trailer`

see [line 317](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/26049f6f9171d1190f3bbe05ec304845cfe6399f/src/net/http/httputil/dump.go#L217) of `go/src/net/http/httputil/dump.go`.

If you do send the request instead dumping it, you will see the header `Content-Length` sent along with `User-Agent` and `Accept-Encoding`.

Comment: yes, so it is unnecessary to set the content-length header in above code. it just strips those headers out of dumped result from `httputil.DumpRequest()` afterwards, although, this header is still there